# Inconsistent jQuery each() behavior with unexplainable fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm writing a plugin based on this handy template for class-based CoffeeScript jQuery plugins: https://gist.github.com/rjz/3610858

Everything works pretty well. However, there is some unexpected behavior at the end when I register the plugin:

```
$.fn.extend markdownAsides: (option, args...) ->
  @each ->
    $this = $(this)
    data = $this.data('markdownAsides')  

    if not data?
      $this.data 'markdownAsides', (data = new MarkdownAsides(this, option))
    if typeof option is 'string'
      data[option].apply(data, args)

    data # Plugin breaks without this line
```

Before I added that final line (a solution I discovered purely on accident), the initial construction of the plugin worked fine, but on successive method calls, the jQuery `each` loop sometimes failed to iterate through every element.

Checking `this.size()` outside the `each` loop returned the correct value, and checking individual elements outside the loop also looked fine. But inside the loop, elements would sometimes be skipped, in a pattern I could not discern.

Like I said, the problem is fixed by adding the final line. (Perhaps the return value of the function being passed to `each` matters somehow?) My question isn't "how do I fix this?" but "why does this work?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning false from the callback function passed to `each` will break out of the loop. I haven't verified but perhaps jQuery will also break on any falsey value except `undefined`.

Since in CoffeeScript there's an implicit return, you were possibly returning something falsey or even false from the callback depending on the operation performed in it.

To avoid any issues, just change `data` for `true` at the end.

Comment: You could also use an explicit `return` in the iterator function to explicitly return nothing at all. AFAIK, jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) checks for exactly `false` rather than any falsy value.